# Creating a Calendar in Symfony

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, web, symfony1

I'm using symfony 1.4 for my web project.

I have the following problem (or opportunity): I need to create a calendar where the "common" user has only the ability to see (or read) the date and time of the events and the "admin" user can edit, add and remove new events. So it's basically a google calendar type of thing where I have to different permissions, read and read, write, delete.

Also I need to be able to fully customize a calendar style so that It matches my css.

How would your approach this problem? I've been trying to find the best plugin for this endeavor but I haven't found one that with a good documentation

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to build 2 applications for that.

1. frontend (read/see)
2. backend (admin)

Just go with the normal symfony approach.. define your models, generate frontend (inkl. modules). There you can adjust you templates and css.

[Practicle open book where you can choose the topics you need](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/)

Then use the admin-generator to get the backend application. You can customize behaviours and styling of course.

Comment: Thanks. How would yo create the calendar? I don't know if theres a built in calendar in symfony that I can use... or any tutorial where I can learn how to create one...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) jQuery plugin. It gives you very nice JavaScript calendar with drag&drop support. You can use your own CSS style.

On the server side create symfony actions that will return data to FullCalendar API. Just serialize the data to JSON [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/).

Of course you should use symfony security component to restrict read/write access. Show only those events that users should be able to see. And don't let them access write actions if they don't have write permission.

To manage event data you can either create backend admin module or display your own form when user click on calendar (like Google Calendar does). If you like the second approach then you have to handle it in JavaScript.