# Symfony Event Calendar

Tags: php, symfony1

I need to have some sort of scheduling I can expand upon in the future to be much more advance, but right now I need a basic event calendar (down to within the day).  I have tried sfEventCalendarPlugin but it looks like it is rather ancient.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208354/creating-a-calendar-in-symfony

Comment: @Imi Borbas, please add your comment to answers so I can accept your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208354/creating-a-calendar-in-symfony).